# Identify the type of an address book record [internal or LDAP] using Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, abaddressbook

The MacOS X address book allows to subscribe to vCards/records using LDAP.

**I need to know, if there exists a well documented Cocoa-based way to identify, if a records comes from LDAP or address book's own / local SQLite DB.**

In case no official way exists, I may try to modify a record. If this fails, I suspect a records comes from an LDAP server.